# wso2 CEP 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT and cassandra. Does it work?

Tags: cassandra, wso2, complex-event-processing

I downloaded wso2 cep 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT from jenkins around 2 weeks ago.

When I configure the cassandra output publisher from cep I tie it to an event stream. When I test the event stream, the cassandra output publisher is invoked and I have an exception. Above the entire log with the exception:

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [DEBUG].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [myAppender] to category [root].
17:12:16,449 INFO  [CassandraHostRetryService] Downed Host Retry service started with queue size -1 and retry delay 10s
17:12:16,517 INFO  [JmxMonitor] Registering JMX me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_EventPublisher_risultato_cassandra:ServiceType=hector,MonitorType=hector
17:12:16,543 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,548 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,549 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,550 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,551 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,552 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,553 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,554 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,558 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,563 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,569 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,576 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,579 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,584 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,589 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,591 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,592 DEBUG [ConcurrentHClientPool] Concurrent Host pool started with 16 active clients; max: 50 exhausted wait: 0
17:12:16,641 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-1>
17:12:16,643 ERROR [HConnectionManager] MARK HOST AS DOWN TRIGGERED for host localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,645 ERROR [HConnectionManager] Pool state on shutdown: <ConcurrentCassandraClientPoolByHost>:{localhost(127.0.0.1):9042}; IsActive?: true; Active: 1; Blocked: 0; Idle: 15; NumBeforeExhausted: 49
17:12:16,646 INFO  [ConcurrentHClientPool] Shutdown triggered on <ConcurrentCassandraClientPoolByHost>:{localhost(127.0.0.1):9042}
17:12:16,647 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-5>
17:12:16,650 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-15>
17:12:16,650 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-4>
17:12:16,652 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-11>
17:12:16,653 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-12>
17:12:16,655 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-14>
17:12:16,655 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-7>
17:12:16,656 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-13>
17:12:16,658 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-9>
17:12:16,659 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-6>
17:12:16,659 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-16>
17:12:16,661 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-2>
17:12:16,663 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-10>
17:12:16,664 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-3>
17:12:16,667 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-8>
17:12:16,669 INFO  [ConcurrentHClientPool] Shutdown complete on <ConcurrentCassandraClientPoolByHost>:{localhost(127.0.0.1):9042}
17:12:16,669 INFO  [CassandraHostRetryService] Host detected as down was added to retry queue: localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,670 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Creating a new thrift connection to localhost(127.0.0.1):9042
17:12:16,670 WARN  [HConnectionManager] Could not fullfill request on this host CassandraClient<localhost:9042-1>
17:12:16,671 WARN  [HConnectionManager] Exception: 
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorTransportException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:39)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$4.execute(AbstractCluster.java:195)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$4.execute(AbstractCluster.java:185)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:104)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:253)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.describeKeyspace(AbstractCluster.java:199)
    at it.vige.test.cassandra.CassandraWso2Test.cassandraConnection(CassandraWso2Test.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:133)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_keyspace(Cassandra.java:1241)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_keyspace(Cassandra.java:1228)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$4.execute(AbstractCluster.java:190)
    ... 28 more
17:12:16,675 ERROR [CassandraHostRetryService] Downed Host retry failed attempt to verify CassandraHost
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:133)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_cluster_name(Cassandra.java:1101)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_cluster_name(Cassandra.java:1089)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService.verifyConnection(CassandraHostRetryService.java:214)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService.access$100(CassandraHostRetryService.java:24)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService$1.run(CassandraHostRetryService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17:12:16,683 INFO  [HConnectionManager] Client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-1> released to inactive or dead pool. Closing.
17:12:16,683 DEBUG [HThriftClient] Closing client CassandraClient<localhost:9042-1>
17:12:16,684 ERROR [CassandraWso2Test] Test fallito
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.getClientFromLBPolicy(HConnectionManager.java:390)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:244)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.describeKeyspace(AbstractCluster.java:199)
    at it.vige.test.cassandra.CassandraWso2Test.cassandraConnection(CassandraWso2Test.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Above how I configure cassandra 2.2.1 in the conf/cassandra.yaml:

```
#cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
cluster_name: 'EventPublisher_risultato_cassandra'
```

and how I start it:

```
.../bin/cassandra
```

Above how the output publisher is configured in the cep:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventPublisher name="risultato_cassandra" statistics="disable"
  trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventpublisher">
  <from streamName="gpsspace_entrati" version="1.0.0"/>
  <mapping customMapping="disable" type="map"/>
  <to eventAdapterType="cassandra">
    <property name="key.space.name">seme</property>
    <property name="port">9042</property>
    <property name="hosts">localhost</property>
    <property name="column.family.name">seme</property>
  </to>
</eventPublisher>
```

Here a test code that emulate the error using :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hectorclient.wso2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.wso2v1</version>
</dependency>
```

as dependency

```
package it.vige.test.cassandra;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.CassandraHostConfigurator;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Cluster;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.ddl.KeyspaceDefinition;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory;

public class CassandraWso2Test {

    private Logger logger = getLogger(getClass());

    @Test
    public void cassandraConnection() {
        try {
            Cluster cluster;

            // Connect to the cluster and keyspace "seme"
            Map<String, String> staticProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
            staticProperties.put("key.space.name", "seme");
            staticProperties.put("replication.factor", null);
            staticProperties.put("port", "9042");
            staticProperties.put("hosts", "localhost");
            staticProperties.put("strategy.class", null);
            staticProperties.put("user.name", null);
            staticProperties.put("indexed.columns", null);
            staticProperties.put("column.family.name", "seme");

            CassandraHostConfigurator chc = new CassandraHostConfigurator();
            chc.setHosts(staticProperties.get("hosts"));
            if (staticProperties.get("port") != null) {
                chc.setPort(Integer.parseInt(staticProperties.get("port")));
            }
            cluster = HFactory.createCluster("EventPublisher_risultato_cassandra", chc, null);

            String keySpaceName = staticProperties.get("key.space.name");

            KeyspaceDefinition existingKeyspaceDefinition = cluster.describeKeyspace(keySpaceName);
            logger.info("existingKeyspaceDefinition = " + existingKeyspaceDefinition);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Test fallito", ex);
            fail();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I configure cassandra I create a keyspace too with this command: $ ./cqlsh
Connected to EventPublisher_risultato_cassandra at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.1 | CQL spec 3.3.0 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE seme WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };

Comment: There is a sample for Cassandra publisher [1] which is working, but it has been tested v1.2.19 not v2.2.1. Need to do a test and confirm weather it supports Cassandra v2.2.1

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Sample+0067+-+Publishing+Map+Events+via+Cassandra+Transport

Answer (score 0):

Enable thrift in cassandra to solve the problem.

nodetool enablethrift

and configure event publisher to connect on 9160 port